# passing parameter using JSP URL to controller in spring mvc, returns 404

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, annotations

First I am getting a list of objects on JSP page, each has an hyperlink(anchor), then on click of anchor I have to send index of the list(surveyId which is also originally coming in surveyList) to controller but the controller is not getting called. It returns 404.

```
<body>
<a href="createSurvey.htm" target="contents">Create a new survey</a>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Existing Surveys</b></td>

    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="survey" items="${surveyList}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>${survey.surveyTitle}</td>
            <td><a id="byParameter"
                href="<c:url value='/home.htm/${surveyList[status.index].surveyId}' />">Share</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
```

URL getting generated is what is need, for example: /project/home.htm/15

This is how the controller looks, I have tried with both @RequestParam and @PathVariable annotations, both return 404. Controller is not getting called.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home.htm/parameter/surveyId=1")
public class UserHomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/home.htm/{surveyId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected String doSubmit(@PathVariable("surveyId") int surveyId, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("userSurvey") UserSurvey userSurvey, BindingResult result)
        throws AdException {
    System.out.println("inside home controller, surveyId:"+surveyId");

    return null;
}
}
```

Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: Which URL do you use ?

Comment: i have changed the code a bit, the annotations part..please see.
I want to return to the same page..
Error: HTTP Status 404 - /project/home.htm/1

Comment: Although I din't get the answer I was looking for, I have rolled back to make your answer look relevant.

Comment: I wanted to retrieve `surveyId` from `"<c:url value='/home.htm/${surveyList[status.index].surveyId}' />"`, which I did not get through @PathVariable...still dint get